# How can I numericaly solve a convection-diffusion equation with a large diffusion term?

Tags: pde, numerical-analysis, advection-diffusion, crank-nicolson

I want to numerically solve the advection-diffusion equation:
\begin{equation}
u_t(x,t) + cu_x(x,t) = v u_{xx}(x,t) 
\end{equation}
for $x \in [0,1]$ and $t \geq 0$ subject to the boundary conditions  $u(0,t) = u(1,t) = 0 $ and $u(x,0) = f(x)$. To compare the accuracy of the numerical solution, I will at first derive the analytical solution.

**Analytical Solution** The solution satisfies 
\begin{equation}
 u(x,t) = h(x,t) \exp \left( \alpha x + \beta t \right) 
\end{equation} 
If one sets $\alpha = c /2v$ and $\beta = - c^{2} / 4v$ the function $h(x,t)$ adheres to the conventional heat equation: $h_t(x,t) = vh_{xx}(x,t)$ suject to $h(0,t) = h(1,t) = 0$ and $h(x,0) = g(x)$. The solution is particularly inexpensive to calculate if one sets $g(x) = \sin ( 2\pi x)$. Then, the function $u$ is: 
\begin{equation}
u(x,t) =  \sin (2 \pi x) \exp  \left( -4 \pi^2 v t - \dfrac{c^2 t}{4v} + \dfrac{cx}{2v} \right )
\end{equation}

**Numerical Solution with BCTS and Crank-Nicolson**
To solve the advection-diffusion equation numerically, I use the BTCS and Crank-Nicolson algorithms. Define first 
\begin{align*}
r &=  \dfrac{v \Delta t}{\Delta x^{2}} \\
R &=  \dfrac{c \Delta t}{\Delta x} 
\end{align*} 
The discretized version of the advection-diffusion equation adherring to the BTCS algorithm is: 
\begin{equation}
u_{k}^{n}(1 + 2r) + u_{k-1}^{n} ( -R/2 - r) + u_{k+1}^{n} (R/2 -r) = u_{k}^{n-1}
\end{equation}
The differential equation for the Crank-Nicolson algorithm can be written as:
\begin{align*}
&u_{k}^{n} ( 1 + r) + u_{k+1}^{n} ( R/4 - r/2)  + u_{k-1}^{n} ( -R/4 - r/2) = \\
& u_{k}^{n-1} ( 1 - r) + u_{k+1}^{n} ( -R/4 + r/2) + u_{k-1}^{n} ( R/4 + r/2) 
\end{align*}

**Simulations** When I solve the advection-diffusion algorithm with $c=1, v=2$ and $\Delta t = 0.001$ and $\Delta x \approx 0.0416 $ the solution looks as follows:
[image]

The analytical solution is both positive and negative, the numerical solution however is an inverted parabola. With  a reduced strength of the diffusion term $v=1/6$ the solution is very accurate:

[image]

How can I compute the numerical solution accurately over a large range of values for $v$?

I am particularly concerned about this question, as I solved the advection-diffusion equation to understand the algorithms and want to apply them to a non-linear PDE of which I don't know the analytical solution. The computer code used for the example is:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import linalg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


class ConvectionDiffusion(object):
    """
    Class to construct solutions to the convection-diffusion equation
    """

    def __init__(self, DELTA_T, M, V, C):
        """
        Parameters:
        -----------
        DELTA_T: scalar(float):
            The time step Delta_t

        M: scalar(float):
            The number of grid-points for x

        V: scalar(float):
            The constant for the diffusion term

        C: scalar(float):
            The constant for the advection term
        """
        self.DELTA_T = DELTA_T
        self.M = M
        self.DELTA_X = 1 / (M - 1)
        self.xVec = np.linspace(0, 1., num=M)
        self.C = C
        self.V = V
        self.R = C * DELTA_T / self.DELTA_X
        self.r = V * DELTA_T / self.DELTA_X**2
        self.u0 = np.sin(2 * np.pi * self.xVec) * \
            np.exp(self.C * self.xVec / (2 * self.V))

    def Implicit(self, stencil, RHS, Sol, l_and_u, T):
        """
        Solving a PDE with implicit algorithms through (banded) matrix inversion

        Parameters:
        -----------
        stencil: fun
            Function defining for each value u^{n-1} the stencil such that
            the discretized PDE can be iterated forward

        RHS: fun
            Constructs the RHS of A x = b.

        l_and_u: tupel(int)
            The number of lower and upper diagonal elements used in stencil to
            use linalg.solve_banded

        T: scalar(float):
            The time at which the solution to the PDE is expressed.

        Sol: fun
            Function generating next periods u^{n} from the solution in
            the interior `x` and the boundary values

        Return:
        -------
        initial: array_like(float):
            The solution to the PDE at time T
        """
        DELTA_T, initial = self.DELTA_T, self.u0
        t = 0.0
        while t < T:
            A = stencil(initial)
            b = RHS(initial)
            x = linalg.solve_banded(l_and_u, A, b)
            initial = Sol(x)
            t = t + DELTA_T
        return initial

    def stencilCN(self, initial):
        """
        Stencil for the Crank-Nicolson algorithm; Stencil * u^n = b

        Parameters:
        ----------
        initial: array_like(float):
            The previous solution

        Returns:
        --------
        A: banded_matrix(float):
            The matrx in baned for to pass it to scipy.linalg.banded_solve
        """
        A = np.zeros((3, len(initial) - 2))
        R, r = self.R, self.r
        A[0, 1:] = R / 4 - r / 2
        A[1, :] = 1 + r
        A[2, :-1] = -R / 4 - r / 2
        return A

    def stencil(self, initial):
        """
        Stencil for the BCTS algorithm, ; Stencil * u^n = u^{n-1}

        Parameters:
        ----------
        initial: array_like(float):
            The previous solution

        Returns:
        --------
        A: banded_matrix(float):
            The matrx in baned for to pass it to scipy.linalg.banded_solve
        """
        A = np.zeros((3, len(initial) - 2))
        R, r = self.R, self.r
        A[0, 1:] = R / 2 - r  # uper diagonal
        A[1, :] = 1 + 2 * r
        A[2, :-1] = -R / 2 - r  # lower diagonal
        return A

    def RHS(self, initial):
        """
        Pepare the RHS for the BCTS algorithm.

        Parameters:
        -----------
        initial: array_like(float):
            The previous solution u^{n-1}

        Returns:
        --------
        b: array_like(float):
            Only the interior values of u^{n-1}
        """
        return initial[1: -1]

    def RHSCN(self, initial):
        """
        Pepare the RHS for the Crank-Nicolson algorithm.

        Parameters:
        -----------
        initial: array_like(float):
            The previous solution u^{n-1}

        Returns:
        --------
        b: array_like(float):
            A weighted sum of previous u^{n-1} values
        """
        R, r = self.R, self.r
        present = initial[1:-1] * (1 - r)
        past =  initial[:-2] * (R / 4 + r / 2)
        future = initial[2:] *(-R / 4 + r / 2)
        b =  present + past + future
        return b

    def Sol(self, x):
        """
        Add the boundary condition

        Parameters:
        x: array_like(float):
            The solution in the interior

        Returns:
        --------
        uNew: array_like(float):
            The entire solution
        """
        uNew = np.zeros(len(x) + 2)
        uNew[1:-1] = x
        return uNew

    def analyticalSol(self, x, T):
        """
        Analytical Solution of the advection-difussion equation

        Parameters:
        -----------
        x   array_like(float):
            The state space
        T:  scalar(float):
            The time at which the solution is evaluated

        Returns:
        v:  array_like(float):
            The solution for the PDE
        """
        C, V = self.C, self.V
        exponential = (- 4 * np.pi**2 * V * T
                       - C**2 * T / (4 * V) + C * x[1:-1] / (2 * V) )
        interior = np.sin(2 * np.pi * x[1:-1]) * np.exp(exponential)
        v = self.Sol(interior)
        return v

    def ComparisonSol(self, T):
        """
        Calculates the analytical solution and the its numercial approximation
        according to the BCTS, C-N and Explicit algorithm at time T

        Parameters:
        T:  scalar(float):
            The time value

        Returns:
        --------
        sol: array_like(float):
            The array with all solutions

        e:  array_like(float):
            The normalized second error norm of each approximation
        """
        xVec, DELTA_T, DELTA_X = self.xVec, self.DELTA_T, self.DELTA_X
        sol, E = np.empty((len(self.u0), 3)), np.zeros(2)

        ## == Anaytical == ##
        sol[:, 0] = self.analyticalSol(xVec, T)

        ## == BTCS == ##
        sol[:, 1] = self.Implicit(self.stencil, self.RHS, self.Sol, (1, 1), T)
        E[0] = np.linalg.norm(sol[:, 0] - sol[:, 1]) / np.linalg.norm(sol[:, 0])

        ## == CN == ##
        sol[:, 2] = self.Implicit(
            self.stencilCN, self.RHSCN, self.Sol, (1, 1), T)
        E[1] = np.linalg.norm(sol[:, 0] - sol[:, 2]) /np.linalg.norm(sol[:, 0])
        return sol, E

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Simulation = ConvectionDiffusion(DELTA_T=0.001, M=50, V=1/6, C=1.)
    y, e = Simulation.ComparisonSol(0.5)
    x = Simulation.xVec
    fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
    ax1.plot(x, y[:, 0], 'b-', label='Anaytical Solution')
    ax1.set_xlabel('x')
    ax1.set_ylabel('Axis Anaytical Solution', color='b')
    ax1.tick_params('y', colors='b')
    ax1.legend(loc=2)

    ax2 = ax1.twinx()
    ax2.plot(x, y[:, 1], 'r--', label='BTCS ')
    ax2.plot(x, y[:, 2], 'r:', label='C-N ')
    ax2.set_ylabel('Axis Numerical Solutions', color='r')
    ax2.tick_params('y', colors='r')
    ax2.legend()
    fig.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Have you tried rescaling your variables?

Comment: @nicoguaro: Thank you for your comment! Can you explain briefly in which situations rescaling facilitates the computation of a numerical solution?

Comment: In general, nondimensionalization is a good idea in general. It might improve the condition number of your system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution you believe to be inaccurate is actually by far the more accurate one; you've simply plotted it in a very deceptive way.  For $\nu=2$, the exact solution is actually no bigger than about $10^{-35}$ everywhere -- it's zero for all intents and purposes.  Therefore the numerical solution is correct to 10 digits -- far better than the accuracy of your solution when $\nu=1/6$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply and putting the numerical solution into perspective. I was a bit worried that the solution doesn't fall below zero, which I interpreted as an error. I learn from your reply that this worry was ill-founded.